# How to properly dput internationalized text?

Tags: r, internationalization

I have a bunch of author names from foreign countries in a CSV which R reads in just fine.  I'm trying to clean them for upload to Mechanical Turk (which really doesn't like even a single internationalized character).  In so doing, I have a question (to be posted later), but I can't even `dput` them in a sensible way:

```
> dput(df[306,"primauthfirstname"])
"Gwena\xeblle M"
> test <- "Gwena\xeblle M"
<simpleError in nchar(val): invalid multibyte string 1>
```

In other words, `dput` works just fine, but pasting the result in fails.  Why doesn't `dput` output the necessary information to allow copy/pasting back into R (presumably all it needs to do is add the encoding attributes the a structure statement?).  How do I get it to do so?

Note that `\xeb` is a valid character as far as R is concerned:

```
> gsub("\xeb","", turk.df[306,"primauthfirstname"] )
[1] "Gwenalle M"
```

But that you can't evaluate the characters individually--it's hex code \x## or nothing:

```
> gsub("\\x","", turk.df[306,"primauthfirstname"] )
[1] "Gwena\xeblle M"
```

Comment: This works fine for me: `(test <- "Gwena\xeblle M")` yields `[1] "Gwenaëlle M"`. I'm using R 2.14.0 with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman What's the `LANG` piece? How do I check it?

Comment: It's an environment variable. Try `Sys.getenv("LANG")`. What version of R are you using?

Comment: "en_US.UTF-8" R2.15.0 linux x64

Comment: For me `test <- "Gwena\xeblle M"` yields `[1] "Gwena\xeblle M"` without the OP's error.  I had the same gsub() errors as the OP though.  I'm on 32-bit Linux, R 2.15.1 with `LANG=en_US.utf8`.

Comment: Just tested it again on a completely fresh Linux Mint install (64-bit R 2.15.1, same LANG variable) and it returned the same error.

Comment: For me, `"Gwena\xeblle M"` yields `"Gwenaëlle M"`, the first `gsub` removes the ë, and the third one does nothing, all as expected, I think. I do not have a `LANG` variable set. I am running this on R 2.15.1 on a 64-bit Windows 7 box. Interestingly, my locale variables are all set to `English_United States.1252`.

Comment: `test` yields `"Gwenaëlle M"`. I'm on a Slovenian locale with a `LANG` values of `en`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dput()`'s helppage says: "Writes an ASCII text representation of an R object". So if your object contains non-ASCII characters, these cannot be represented and have to be converted somehow.

So I would suggest you use `iconv()` to convert your vector before `dput`ing. One approach is:

```
> test <- "Gwena\xeblle M"
> out <- iconv(test, from="latin1", to="ASCII", sub="byte")
> out
[1] "Gwena<eb>lle M"
> gsub('<eb>', 'ë', out)
[1] "Gwenaëlle M"
```

which, as you see, works both ways. You can later use `gsub()` to back-convert bytes into characters (if your encoding supports it, e.g. utf-8).

The second approach is simpler (and I guess preferable for your needs), but works one-way and your libiconv may not support it:

```
> test <- "Gwena\xeblle M"
> iconv(test, from="latin1", to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "Gwenaelle M"
```

Hope this helps!