# Where is this whitespace hiding?

Tags: regex, r

I have a character vector which is the file of some PDF scraping via `pdftotext` (command line tool).

Everything is (blissfully) nicely lined up.  However, the vector is riddled with a type of whitespace that eludes my regular expressions:

```
> test
[1] "Address:"              "Clinic Information:"   "Store "                "351 South Washburn"    "Aurora Quick Care"    
[6] "Info"                  "St. Oshkosh, WI 54904" "Phone: 920‐232‐0718"   "Pewaukee"  

> grepl("[0-9]+ [A-Za-z ]+",test)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> dput(test)
c("Address:", "Clinic Information:", "Store ", "351 South Washburn", 
"Aurora Quick Care", "Info", "St. Oshkosh, WI 54904", "Phone: 920‐232‐0718", 
"Pewaukee")

> test.pasted <- c("Address:", "Clinic Information:", "Store ", "351 South Washburn", 
+                  "Aurora Quick Care", "Info", "St. Oshkosh, WI 54904", "Phone: 920‐232‐0718", 
+                  "Pewaukee")

> grepl("[0-9]+ [A-Za-z ]+",test.pasted)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> Encoding(test)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"

> Encoding(test.pasted)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"   "unknown"
```

Clearly there's some character that's not getting assigned in the `dput`, as in the question below:

[How to properly dput internationalized text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369390/how-to-properly-dput-internationalized-text)

I can't copy/paste the entire vector....  How do I search-and-destroy this non-whitespace whitespace?

**Edit**

Clearly I wasn't even close to clear because answers are all over the place.  Here's an even simpler test case:

```
> grepl("Clinic Information:", test[2])
[1] FALSE
> grepl("Clinic Information:", "Clinic Information:") # Where the second phrase is copy/pasted from the screen
[1] TRUE
```

There is a single space between the word "Clinic" and "Information" printed on the screen and in the `dput` output, but whatever is in the string is not a standard space.  My goal is to eliminate this so I can properly grep that element out.

Comment: That whitespace is not in the vector itself, it's just in the way it is displayed.

Comment: Take a look at `lapply(test[4], utf8ToInt)` and see if there are any big numbers in there.

Comment: @AlanCurry `> lapply(test[4], utf8ToInt)
 [1]  51  53  49 160  83 111 117 116 104 160  87  97 115 104  98 117 114 110`

Comment: The 160 is your issue. It's a non-breaking space. You could match it (and a few other weird types of spaces) by using a Unicode category in a perl-style regexp: grepl("[0-9]+\\p{Zs}[A-Za-z ]+",test,perl=TRUE)

Comment: @AlanCurry, could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrading my comment to an answer:

Your string contains a non-breaking space (U+00A0) which got translated to a normal space when you pasted it. Matching all the strange space-like characters in Unicode is easy with a perl-style regular expression:

```
grepl("[0-9]+\\p{Zs}[A-Za-z ]+", test, perl=TRUE)
```

The perl regexp syntax is `\p{categoryName}`, the extra backslash is part of the syntax of a string containing a backslash, and "Zs" is the "Separator" Unicode category, "space" subcategory. A simpler method for just the U+00A0 character would be

```
grepl("[0-9]+[ \\xa0][A-Za-z ]+", test)
```

Comment: I'm confused. test[2] wouldn't match anyway, it has no digits in it to match the [0-9] part.

Comment: You're right of course.  Should've read the regex before running it blindly.  Works perfectly once I get the offending digits out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after trailing and leading white space.  If so maybe this function will work:

```
Trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
```

Also keep an eye out for tabs and such and this may be useful:

```
clean <- function(text) {
    gsub("\\s+", " ", gsub("\r|\n|\t", " ", text))
}
```

so use the clean and then the Trim as in:

```
Trim(clean(test))
```

Also be on the look out for the en dash (–) and the em dash (—)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything unusual about the whitespace, but the dashes in the phone numbers are `U+2010 (HYPHEN)`, not the ASCII hyphen (`U+002D`).

Answer (score 0):

```
test <- c("Address:", "Clinic Information:", "Store ", "351 South Washburn", 
"Aurora Quick Care", "Info", "St. Oshkosh, WI 54904", "Phone: 920‐232‐0718", 
"Pewaukee")

> grepl("[0-9]+ [A-Za-z ]+",test)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE


library(stringr)
test2 <- str_trim(test, side = "both")

> grepl("[0-9]+ [A-Za-z ]+",test2)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# So there were no spaces in the vector, just the screen output in this case.
```